# Explain how can we Traverse all individual li by using only one parent class?

Tags: html, css, parent-child, selector, traversal

I want to traverse all individual li by using only one parent class eg: "here we using mainDiv" How can we do this in css3? not in Jquery or javascript.

```
css:
    .mainDiv ul li:nth-child(1){
       color:red;
    }
   .mainDiv ul li:nth-child(2){
           color:blue;
        }
   .mainDiv ul li:nth-child(3){
           color:yellow;
        }
```

> kindly mention below code

Like wise i want to traverse the second set of ul > li (a,b,c) by using only one parent class name (mainDiv). How can i do this by css3?

HTML:

```
 <div class="mainDiv">

    <ul>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question this HTML code could be helpful.

```
<head>
    <style>
        /* all list items will be blue */
        .my-class li {
            color: blue;
        }

        /* only second list will be bold */
        .my-class ul:nth-child(2) li {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /* all third list items will be underline */
        .my-class ul li:nth-child(3) {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my-class">
        <ul>
            <li>x</li>
            <li>y</li>
            <li>z</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <br>
<pre> /* only second list will be bold */
        .my-class ul:nth-child(2) li {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
</pre>

</br> </br>
This code will affect the "bold" for all li in the 2nd ul. but i need individual li.
</br> </br>
eg:
</br> </br>
<code>
 /* only second list will be bold */
        .my-class ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) {
            color:red;
   }
</code>
</br> </br>
this code is not affecting the second li (i.e:"b")
 .my-class ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly of what you're asking when saying 'traversing'. But if it's matching certain elements, the css you provided does almost what you're asking for.

To match any li under mainDiv:

```
.mainDiv li {
   // my css
}
```

To match only those in the second ul:

```
.mainDiv ul:last-child li {
   // my css
}
```

Note that `:last-child` allows to select the last child of mainDiv. Other solutions could have been to use (among others) `ul:nth-child(2)` or `ul:nth-of-type(2)`